ArgoCD PostSync Hook how to send GitHub revision
We have a argocd setup running on EKS, Source code management system we are using is GitHub.
Is it possible to get the GitHub revision from the Post Sync job ?
Wanted to get the exact commit revision from the post sync job when there are multiple commits happening to same repository
Using ArgoCD API or PostSync Job can we achieve this ?
